# How to run two Zeus servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zeus

I have several projects in different folders, can I run several Zeus instances, with different port for each one?

I have gotten till https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/docs/ruby/modifying.md. But I have no clue if this can be done.

Added rails tag as people using rails could know about this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can - you don't need to do anything, because Zeus is using unix domain sockets rather than tcp (unlike spork for example)

Say you're working on 2 apps. When you are in the root folder of the first app and you run `zeus start`, zeus creates a socket called zeus.sock in that folder. When you run various zeus commands in that folder, it finds that socket and uses it to talk to the zeus server.

Meanwhile your second app will have its own zeus.sock file, also in its folder. Commands run in that folder will find that socket rather than the first.